# How to play mp4 from variable instead of file in python and PyQt5?

Tags: python, encryption, video, pyqt5, media-player

I am using Python 3.8.2 and PyQt5 for development .

I could build a video player app that can play video files like mp4 and etc .

because of some encryption , i need to play the video from variable instead of file .

is that possible ? and how can i do that  ?

may be the attached diagram helps . [Work Flow Of My Encrypt Video Player-Need Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bkiT.jpg)

***NOTE : after much search . It's better to say my question in another way . 
How To Play "bytearray" Variable as video ?

***NOTE : More Detailed Question : 
How Does
self.mediaplayer.setMedia(QMediaContent**(QUrl.fromStringList()))**
Work ? Does It Solve My Problem ?

Comment: The only solution I know is "PIPEing" the data to FFmpeg. MP4 file format is problematic in that case. There is something called "moov atom" that must be at the beginning of the file (the MP4 file must be created in a specific way). The video playing is going to be sequential (unless you decode all raw frames into the RAM).

Comment: I'll Try . Thanks so Much friend

Comment: If you can access the decripted data and you're using QMediaPlayer, you could subclass your own QIODevice, and overwrite its [`readData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readData) to provide the decrypted data.

Comment: Thanks so much bro